# Import properties of markers from e.g. txt file?

Tags: javascript, leaflet

First, please correct the tags if they are wrong. Not sure about where this belongs to.
I want to add markers to my OpenStreetMap which is running with leaflet. I added them manually one by one into my html file but it just looks bad. I already have some ideas on how to add them using a `for` loop. But my problem now is that I don't want to make a new array for every marker I need. I saw someone using a table and getting the information out of that. Don't remember what and where it was.

My marker look like that: `Name = L.marker([lat,lon]).addTo(overlay).bindPopop("Info for marker")`
Now, is it possible to write a table in e.g. a text file where the first row says "Name, lat, lon, overlay, info", the next rows give properties and JS or any other module gets the information I need? If so, how? If not, how then?^^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to consider putting the data in a list of JavaScript objects (aka JSON in this case). It's easy enough to write and you don't need to parse things.

```js
const markers = [
  {lat: 123, lon: 456, text: 'Info'},
  {lat: 123, lon: 456, text: 'Info'},
  {lat: 123, lon: 456, text: 'Info'},
  {lat: 123, lon: 456, text: 'Info'},
  {lat: 123, lon: 456, text: 'Info'},
];
markers.forEach(({lat, lon, text}) => L.marker([lat, lon]).addTo(overlay).bindPopop(text));
```

If you really *do* want a text format, we can do that too...

```js
const markersText = `
123,456,Info
123,456,Info
123,456,Info
123,456,Info
`;
// Converts the above text format into a similar `markers` list-of-objects:
const markers = markersText
  .split("\n") // split by newlines
  .filter(Boolean) // remove empty lines
  .map(line => line.trim().split(",")) // split each line by comma
  .map(([lat, lon, text]) => ({  // map the arrays to objects
    lat: parseFloat(lat),
    lon: parseFloat(lon),
    text,
  }));
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer! Will it work too when I write all the markers in one JS file and import them to my html file writing only ``markers.forEach(({lat, lon, text}) => L.marker([lat, lon]).addTo(overlay).bindPopop(text));`` in html?

Comment: Sure, it should, if I'm understanding your question correctly.

Comment: So, my map still works. But I don't see any overlays. HTML file looks like [this](https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/zC5tXYdZ9n/). Did I made anything wrong?

Comment: Even with changing 'AAA', 'BBB' and 'CCC' to 'map' it only shows the first marker and no popup

Comment: What are `aaa`, `bbb` and `ccc`?

Comment: Look at the link behind [this](https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/zC5tXYdZ9n/). There you can see my HTML file. These are 3 different layerGroups. That's why there is ``L.control.layers(null, overlays).addTo(map);``. But still won't work changing it to map directly. Only 1 marker

Comment: I can see the link, but I don't see the declarations for `aaa`, `bbb` and `ccc`, which you're `forEach`ing through. Do you see any errors in your browser console?

Comment: ```var AAA = L.layerGroup();
var BBB = L.layerGroup();
var CCC = L.layerGroup();```  

They were made to layerGroups and should filled with the markers

Comment: Browser says ``TypeError: L.marker(...).addTo(...).bindPopop is not a function``

Comment: It should probably be `bindPopup`.

Comment: Also, `aaa` is not the same as `AAA`.

Comment: There is no ``aaa``, ``bbb`` or ``ccc``.

Comment: "It should probably be bindPopup. – AKX 8 mins ago" I deleted every ``.bindPopup(text)`` and now everything works fine. But it's useless without popups